# cancancan block conditions for nested attributes :new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

I have two resources vehicle and car, they are associated through vehicle has_many car,car has_one vehicle.

```
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource find_by: :title

class CarsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :vehicle, find_by: :title
  load_and_authorize_resource through: :vehicle, singleton: true
```

Now if I want to to only load new action of car when the attribute cost of vehicle is more than 5.

```
can :new, car do |c|
 c.vehicle.cost > 5
end
```

I am not able to get desired results.As for new action the object is not yet created is there no way to access that attribute or do I need to specify anything else in controller?

Comment: It should be `vehicle has_many :cars` or is that just a typo on SO? Car is a regular countable noun.

Comment: Yes, that is how its is in the model I just tried to mention the association here.

Comment: Well, start by using the proper pluralization and drop `singleton: true`.

Comment: It should also be `car belongs_to :vehicle` since the `vehicle_id` foreign key should be on the `cars` table. You use `has_one` for one-to-one assocations on the side without the foreign key.

Comment: I would really post your models as a seperate question here since they seem botched and you need to resolve that before you can get authorization to work anyways.